# How to plot 1d binary to a 2d graph and taking the highest peak of 1's and outputting that?

Tags: python, graph, binary

So basically I have no clue how I would take 3 inputs (height, width and a sequence of binary code) and plot it into a 2d graph of 1's and 0's (see image), and from that take the highest peak of 1's (without any 0's in between) and output that as a decimal number.

[image]

So for example this is 8x10 (input 1 would be 8 (height) and input 2 would be 10 (widht)) and the third input being the binary list. From the binary list inserted into the 8x10 graph the highest peak (in green) would be the output as regular decimal, 5 in this case. Is there any way to do that in the most standard python possible?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is first reshape the 1d array to the desired 2d dimension. Then, it's just traversing in proper row and columns to calculate the max peak.

```py
import numpy as np

oned_bin = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
print(len(oned_bin))

row = 8
col = 10

twod_bin = np.reshape(oned_bin, (row, col))
print(twod_bin)
print(twod_bin.shape)

# find longest peak
max_p = 0
for c in range(col):
    cur_p = 0
    for r in range(row-1, -1, -1): # reverse traversal
        if twod_bin[r][c] != 1:
            break
        else:
            cur_p += 1
            max_p = max(max_p, cur_p)

print(max_p)
```

```
80
[[1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
(8, 10)
5
```

without using numpy,

```
from functools import reduce 
from operator import mul

def reshape(lst, shape):
    if len(shape) == 1:
        return lst
    n = reduce(mul, shape[1:])
    return [reshape(lst[i*n:(i+1)*n], shape[1:]) for i in range(len(lst)//n)]

oned_bin = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
print(len(oned_bin))

row = 8
col = 10

twod_bin = reshape(oned_bin, (row, col))
print(twod_bin)


# find longest peak
max_p = 0
for c in range(col):
    cur_p = 0
    for r in range(row-1, -1, -1): # reverse traversal
        if twod_bin[r][c] != 1:
            break
        else:
            cur_p += 1
            max_p = max(max_p, cur_p)

print(max_p)
```

Comment: I see, but what about not using numpy? Is that a possibility?

Comment: That is pretty obvious, just need to rewrite the reshape function, added it.